# How can I view the progress of long-running Cassandra operations?

Tags: cassandra, progress-bar

Several operations in Cassandra seem to take a long time to complete, and I'm trying to determine ways to get insight into their progress, or determine if the system has stalled.

The two I'm specifically interested in are:

- `nodetool decommission`
- `nodetool repair`

[This](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201108.mbox/%3C4CDCDAB3-6E52-4182-B033-E5B1DDBCA114@thelastpickle.com%3E) seems to suggest that you can use `nodetool compactionstats` to view the progress of `nodetool repair`, but `nodetool compactionstats` doesn't output anything that I can derive progress from. Compaction jobs come and go, but the number of pending jobs seems to hover around 40. There's also a timer at the bottom, and it *appears* to be going down, but it is going down very slowly. (<s>I'd say it's going down by about 3 minutes every 10 minutes?</s> It just quadrupled.)

A chat-room suggested I use `nodetool netstats` to "view the streams" for decommission, but again, this just show me that some "streams" are occurring, and how complete they are. Most are listed as 100% (or more, in some cases!), and occasionally, they all are, but a new stream will come along, so I'm in the dark as to how this conveys progress of a decom.

Comment: Agree with this. Not only with repair and decom; but also with compaction & bootstrap. Usually, these operations are divided into smaller tasks and nodetool/logs only show the progress and estimate for the current tasks. There's no way to tell how complete the whole operation is.

Answer (score 1):

I think datastax provide a OpsCentre which can show the progress of the activities on the Activity bar.

Each of the cassandra nodes need to run datastax-agent.

Check it out here: http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter

I am not sure whether there is a command line tool to do the same